# Bloqueo usando la clase de Java FileWriter

Tags: java, hilos, filewriter

Estoy tratando de escribir un archivo usando la clase entregada java "FileWriter". Este programa usa varios hilos. Me preguntaba cómo puedo controlar la escritura de este archivo (con bloqueos u otros métodos) para no generar ninguna condición de carrera en la escritura de este archivo.

Gracias.

Atentamente.

Comment: Aunque tengas varios hilos, ¿necesitas que todos los hilos escriban? ¿O lo puedes organizar para que un hilo escriba y el resto le facilite los datos al hilo escritor?

Answer (score 0):

Hecha un vistazo a la clase, Semaphore de Java para controlar la concurrencia.

[Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html)

Basicamente declaras un semaforo con un numero de pasos que pueden dar los metodos. Cada vez que un Hilo de ejecucion quiera escribir en el fichero debe de comprobar si el semaforo "esta en verde", es decir no hay otro hilo de ejecucion escribiendo. En caso de comenzar a escribir, pone el semaforo "en rojo", es decir impide a los demas hilos de ejecucion acceder al fichero.

La espera del semaforo debes hacerla en un while para que quede a la espera hasta que la clase semaforo returne un true y pueda escribir en el fichero.

Otra opcion es utilizar thread.wait y thread.notify que pondran a la espera a los demas hilos y con notify los despertaras. Recuerda tambien poner los metodos en Synchronized para mejor sincronizacion entre hilos y establecerles prioridades a los hilos para evitar problemas de concurrencia.

[Synchronized java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Un saludo.